# Cannot Connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 from Sharepoint Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on dbserver and Sharepoint 2010 on webserver. When trying to configure Sharepoint to use the database installed on dbserver, it says it cannot connect. Then I installed SSMS on Sharepoint server and tried to connect to the Database Engine on dbserver but it throwed following error. 
"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893007)"

Surprisingly, I am able to connect to Analysis Services installed on dbserver from Sharepoint server. And am also able to connect to dbserver from third server. We don't need SSL enabled on any server.

Please help. Searched net and tried many options but in vain.

Comment: Error says that the algorithm which both servers are using for pre-login handshake is not matching. How do we know which algorithm servers are using?

Answer (score 1):

Finally after so many days, it got solved:)
As the error says that server and client does not possess a common algorithm, I checked all the SSL algorithm parameters and finally found some difference in Sharepoint server and DB server. Removed this difference and things started working.

To check for these parameters go to registry (regedit) 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL
Check all the values underneath this Key. For me, it was Hashes Key which was different in Sharepoint Server. Changed that to make it same as DB server and they started communicating.

SCHANNEL is Microsoft implementation of SSL.

Hope this helps others in saving time.